# How would I use width in @media queries in css

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am setting width inside @media, but is not working! How would I accomplish this? Here is my code:

```
mat-toolbar {
    app-toolbar-left {
        width: 35%;
    }

    app-toolbar-right {
        width: 22%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    app-toolbar-left {
        width: 25%;
    }

    app-toolbar-right {
        width: 17%;
        margin-right: 1.5%;
    }
}
```

My doubt is the css `margin-right` is working, but why is the `width` not? Just appear in google dev tools, but has a trace over... Did I forget something? If I set !important it works, but I know is not a good practice.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    mat-toolbar {
        app-toolbar-left {
            width: 25%;
        }

        app-toolbar-right {
            width: 17%;
            margin-right: 1.5%;
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is just because your selectors are less detailed in your media queries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is not working.... is chrome dev tools just appear trace.... you know why?

Comment: Maybe it's another problem of specifity. What is the selector overriding the width in your media queries ?

Comment: Well, nothing, in the file just have that script... haha =(

Comment: You said that you can see your style in the dev tools but that it is deactivated, so it means that there is another style overriding it and you should be able to see it in the dev tools as well.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Is overriding by width: 35%! =) If I disable that width: 35%, is working....

Comment: Best practice: Try **not** to use `!important` in your code.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! Well, I used another approach, defined @media (max-width: 1024) to width: 35% is working! Is good practice? haha

Comment: Alright, what is the selector applying this `width: 35%` ?

Comment: app-toolbar-left, before @media query

Comment: Also, define what the media query is for, e.g. `@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)`.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! But have some another way for that? haha I guess is not good practice to use @media (max-width) all the time.... or not? =)

Answer (score 0):

If those are CSS classes (you didn't mention anything else), you need to use a dot before the class names, like

```
.app-toolbar-left { 
  ... 
}
.app-toolbar-right  {
  ...
}
```

etc.

The media query itself is written correctly, but if these are CSS classes (and not some framework), you need those dots for the classes in the stylesheet.